# What is difference between :: and . in C# when aliases are used?

Tags: c#

If alias is used with namespaces like

```
using alias = System;
```

there are two ways to call members of namespace through alias:

```
alias::member
```

and

```
alias.member
```

Is there any difference between these calls?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the difference would be in case you have an additional identifier with name `alias` in your scope, e.g. a class. In that case, `alias.member` would search for a member on that class instead of using the `alias` namespace.

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) for the MSDN documentation

Comment: Indeed, that's the difference. The C# spec (v5, Section 9.7) says the same: *"Unlike the regular . qualifier, the left-hand identifier of the :: qualifier is looked up only as an extern or using alias."*

Comment: Also `::` is really nice because it explicitly flags that an aliased type is being accessed. `.` access is used everywhere in the language, while `::` is specialized